# Android does not allow directory creation with SDK update

Tags: android, sdk, create-directory

Strange issue, but on one device Android no longer lets the app create a directory (or any directories). This seems to have happened since I moved to SDK 27 (I brought in a 3rd party library that requires the upgrade). Even stranger, it works on other devices. The device that does not work is a Samsung Galaxy Tab S3, running Android 8 (sdk 26).

Here is the code that fails:

```
public static String mediaStorageDirectory() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "myapp";
}

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1); 
    File dbPath = new File(Utilities.mediaStorageDirectory() + "/databases/");
    if (!dbPath.exists()) {
        if (dbPath.mkdirs()) {
            this.mContext = context;
            createDataBase();
        }
    }
}
```

The code creates a directory, then copies the app DB in into that directory. This code has been working since the dawn of time...has Android changed some security requirements for file creation?

If you are wondering, I have set privileges as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And the user is prompted for those privileges successfully before the creation of the directory structure.

Comment: It is unclear which path you use. Further your code is messy and you even try to create a database when the directory cannot ne created. Please write cleaner code to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps I have added the code that generates the path to the media storage. You assume I wrote this code - I did not, it has been around long before I inherited it, thus the quote "working since the dawn of time".  I have "cleaned " it up for your review, minus try/catch handling to boil it down to the code having issues. thx

Comment: You do not need any permission for getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: If that path/directory already exists a database file will not be created. Is this intentionally?

Comment: Yes. It only needs to be created once when the application is first run. From there we do not want to re-create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to be related to SDK 27. Seems they are now requiring (enforcing?) that the permissions for WRITE be granted. Previously only READ was required. I would assume that this was related to security upgrades, but I could not find any documentation on this change. Perhaps everyone else just did the inclusion previously. For those wanting to see code that does the permissions handling, I pulled the following code from another Stack Overflow a while back. I merely added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE part that was previously missing:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

public void checkPermissions() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Camera");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read External Storage");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Write External Storage");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Record Audio");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++) {
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            }

            message = message + "." + " If you do not the application may not function correctly.";

            showMessageOKCancel(message, this,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}

private static void showMessageOKCancel(String message, Activity activity, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK", okListener).create().show();
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All Permissions Granted
            }
            // Warn the user that the application will not run
            else if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("File Read Permissions Not Granted");
                builder.setMessage("The Application cannot operate without READ access to files on your device. Do you want to grant this access?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
                if (!isFinishing())
                    builder.show();
            }
            // Warn the user that the application will not run
            else if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("File Write Permissions Not Granted");
                builder.setMessage("The Application cannot operate without WRITE access to directories on your device. Do you want to grant this access?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
                if (!isFinishing())
                    builder.show();
            }else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

The call is SDK specific, added to the OnCreate() of your main activity:

```
    // Check permissions for Android 6.0 devices
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        checkPermissions();
    }
```